# Please use hyperlinks instead of raw URLs

Tags: discussion, faq, formatting

Instead of writing:

> "I have been following the example laid out in: [https://github.com/maxhutch/deprecated-quantum-espresso/blob/master/PHonon/examples/example15/reference/zno.ph.in"](https://github.com/maxhutch/deprecated-quantum-espresso/blob/master/PHonon/examples/example15/reference/zno.ph.in%22)

the following looks better:

> "I have been following the example laid out in [this file](https://github.com/maxhutch/deprecated-quantum-espresso/blob/master/PHonon/examples/example15/reference/zno.ph.in)"

One thing that separates MMSE from a lot of other sites, is the above-average standards for layout, formatting, spelling, grammar, general look-and-feel, etc. By spending a few extra seconds, you can help us maintain our high standards :)

Comment: Also I think it is good to indicate what the hyperlink contains. So in the above example, it would be better to say : “I have been following the example laid out in [Deprecated-Quantum-espresso-repo](https://github.com/maxhutch/deprecated-quantum-espresso/tree/master)”